# Return specific contour that includes a certain pixel coordinate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working with an image like this:

[image]

What I need is a list with all the contours that touch the top AND the bottom of the image. Currently, what I am doing is i find all the contours of the image and then I iterate through them in order to discard the ones that dont satisfy the condition. My code is as follows:

```
contours, hier= cv2.findContours(projection,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)    
for contour in contours:
 if 0 in contour[:,0,1] and rows in contour[:,0,1]:
  validContours.append(contour)
```

I need this to run as fast as possible, so I would just like to just do the checking for the for the first row of pixels.

I think the long but sure way of doing this is implementing another algorithm from the ground up.

Another idea that I have is using the floodfill function algorithm in order to color a blank image another image with the pixel data and then only transfer this data to a "finished" image such that I only have the colored data.

If anyone has any suggestion I would gladly accept them!

Comment: don't work with contours. get all connected components, with stats. filter for which of them have a bounding box that touches the top/bottom edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use Flood Fill algorithm.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('VlKak.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w = im.shape
mask = im.copy()
mask[0, :] = 255
mask[-1, :] = 255
flood_fill = cv2.floodFill(mask, None, (0, 0), 0)[1]
flood_fill = cv2.floodFill(flood_fill, None, (h, 0), 0)[1]
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(im, flood_fill)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks your answer pointed me in the right direction. In the result yo shared I can se that the resulting blobs are touching either the top OR the bottom. I needed all that are touching both.
Here is how I modified it:

mask1 = projection.copy()
mask2 = projection.copy()

mask1[0,:]= 255
mask2[-1,:]= 255
flood_fill1 = cv2.floodFill(mask1, None, (0, 0), 0)[1]
flood_fill2 = cv2.floodFill(mask2, None, (h, 0), 0)[1]

result1= cv2.bitwise_xor(projection,flood_fill1)
result2= cv2.bitwise_xor(projection,flood_fill2)
projection= cv2.bitwise_and(result1, result2)